# What type of cheese is used on Patsy's Old Fashioned Margherita Pizza

Tags: baking, cheese, pizza, mozzarella

I am trying to figure out the specific type of cheese used on the Patsy's Old Fashioned Margherita pizza.  I don't think it's buffalo or another fresh mozzarella because they appear to be thin slices.

The description of the pizza on their website's [menu](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57d07a34b8a79bd7a76c3381/t/5ced6c9c8165f501770dab7d/1559063708695/pasty+dine+menu.pdf) just says "mozzarella."

Any guesses?

[image: Patsy's Original Margherita]

Answer (score 2):

You can buy firm, sliced [or grated, of course] mozzarella in [supermarkets](https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/gol-ui/product/sliced-grated-cheese/sainsburys-mozzarella-slices-x10-250g) for sandwiches or pizza topping.
[I've never tried it, I can't imagine it would be to my taste] but I see no reason it couldn't be some commercial application of 'firm' mozzarella, as opposed to trying to slice the good stuff, supplied in its own whey, which I use for everything from tricolore/caprese to pizza topping.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozzarella) describes this as "Low-moisture part-skim mozzarella" which sounds… ermm… delicious ;)

> Low-moisture part-skim mozzarella, widely used in the food-service industry, has a low galactose content, per some consumers' preference for cheese on pizza to have low or moderate browning. Some pizza cheeses derived from skim mozzarella variants were designed not to require aging or the use of starter. Others can be made through the direct acidification of milk.

Comment: The cheese on the Patsy's pizza just looks so white.  All the sliced mozzarellas I have seen are either fresh mozz or somewhat yellow.

Comment: One would imagine the cheaper & faster you can make it, the less yellow it's going to be. Pizza cheese is going to be way down that scale. Your picture shows it browning quite substantially, which seems to fit that.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I read on pizzamaking.com that they make thier own fior di latte, fresh cow mozzarella. I've never been to Patsy's.